# Path to relative pages points to the redirected domain not original

Tags: html, angularjs, redirect

I have a project that is hosted as subdomain of some engine. So, its actual address is **mysite.parentsite.com**

I set up the redirection from my domain to this site that now, when you put **coolsite.com** into the addressbar of browser you will be redirected to **mysite.parentsite.com** and it's done transparent (masked) so the end user sees ONLY **coolsite.com** and never **mysite.parentsite.com**.

The problem is I use relative links in the layout. And now, if link is something like

```
<a href="/item/12345">item</a>
```

it will actually show **mysite.parentsite.com/item/12345** instead **coolsite.com/item/12345**

I can change all the links on-the-fly with angular function using the origin domain address to make them absolute like

```
<a href="http://coolsite.com/item/12345">item</a>
```

but maybe there is some more natural way to do it.

Thanks.

UPDATE. I figured out what was wrong. The paths themselves were okay, I mean you always can use relative paths even if you are doing the redirection. The browser is smart enough to figure out the absolute path from a relative one.

The problem was I did one more unnecessary redirection. So instead of

coolsite.com --> mysite.parentsite.com

I actually did

coolsite.com --> mysite.parentsite.com --> parentsite.com

As soon as I remove the middle tier everything started working:

coolsite.com -->  parentsite.com

Comment: A *redirect* is sending the user to a different page. Once you redirect them, they are no longer on coolsite.com but rather on mysite.parentsite.com. So of course the relative links are to mysite.parentsite.com -- that's where they are, so that's where the links are relative to....

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas, the redirection now works completely transparent for the end users. I'm looking for some way to implement this transparency because user still sees coolsite.com not the site he is redirected to. I suspect I want something impossible but "masked redirection" looks impossible too but works :) I updated the post to be more clear.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas please see the update. Relative links work perfect if you don't add one more tier as I did.

Comment: OK? So do you still have a problem?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas not anymore, thanks.